# MOUSE_OUT outside of a movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, actionscript

I'm having a little problem here,
I'm new to Actionscript 3, and what I'm trying to do is build a navigation menu.
What I did is I made a movieclip, added two listeners to it, MOUSE_OVER, and MOUSE_OUT,

the MOUSE_OVER tells the menu to play, so it then animates the opening of it,

the problem though, that when I put my mouse on the buttons themselves, the menu thinks that the mouse is out of it,

I understand that the mouse left the menu itself and entered some other object,
I thought of making a new rectangle, and on the mouse out, to check whether the mouse is really out of the menu's regions, it didn't work though,

I'd be glad to know how to do that,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` event which fires only if you your mouse is out of the clip and **all its children** whereas `MOUSE_OUT` only considers the clip itself.

Comment: Thank you, it did work, the problem now though is that when I put my mouse on the buttons, it reactivates the MOUSE_OVER listener, tried to see if theres a ROLL_IN, I guess there isnt?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#ROLL_OVER